# Recive background notifcation iOS Swift 5 (Without body and title)

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, background-process

I am trying to receive a notification in the background to process information in my App when it is in Foreground, Background or Closed. I don't want to receive the Alert.

I have tried to do it without placing the Title and Body at the time of shipment, only Custom Data.

How could I receive this information without using an alert, regardless of the status of the App?

Answer (score 0):

A **silent push notification** or some might call it **background notification** is a notification that does not trigger any alert or sound. It wakes up your app and allows you to perform any non-UI related operations in the background.

Sample payload for a background notification:

```
{ "aps" : { "content-available" : 1 }, "acme1" : "bar","acme2" : 42 }
```

You need to add “Background Modes” and “Push Notifications” capabilities in Xcode in order for your app to be able to receive a silent push notification.

Points to note:

1. You can only test push notifications in a real iOS device. iOS
   simulator will not be able to receive any push notifications.
2. The background operation triggered by a silent push notification
   will have roughly 30 seconds of execution time.
3. Silent push notifications will not work when the device is in Low
   Data Mode.

[Apple guideline for this topic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app) to refer in more details.